Keep getting "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect." whenever I try to start a program through command line
I'm trying to run a program through command line using this command
cdC:\Program Files (x86)\GameSave Manager v3>start gs_mngr_3

No matter that I've copied the file path directly from the file explorer, or how I modify the path, removing spaces, parentheses, etc. every time I get The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect I've tried opening other programs (firefox, steam) with the same method as well, to the same result

That's not a command, it's two commands mashed together. You seem to have a cd command that changes into a directory and a start command that opens a file, but if you want to put two commands in one line, only & or && works as the separator – not >.
(> is actually the output redirection operator, which means "write the output of cd into a file named start". If you happen to find an empty file named 'start' in your user directory, that's where it came from.)
Also, don't modify the path. If the path is C:\Program Files (x86)\, then C:\ProgramFilesx86 will not be the path. If it has spaces, put it in double-quotes.

For example:
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\GameSave Manager v3"
start gs_mngr_3

or in a single line (using Cmd-syntax && separator):
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\GameSave Manager v3" && start gs_mngr_3

The start is not needed for .exe files; they can be run directly using their name:
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\GameSave Manager v3" && .\gs_mngr_3


Most programs don't need an explicit cd and can be run (using their whole path) regardless of your shell's current location:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\GameSave Manager v3\gs_mngr_3"

if it's already an .exe or .cmd; or as:
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\GameSave Manager v3\gs_mngr_3"

for other files. (Note that the start command in Cmd is weird, and if you want to start a double-quoted path, you have to include an extra double-quoted "window title" parameter before it, such as the "" in the above example.)



And if you are currently on a different drive, you have to use cd with the /d option.


You don't need to cd /d into the .\directory and then run your Program
You have the option to do it directly with:
Start " /D <working in this directory> <running this file>:

:: Start an application and specify where files will be saved (Working Directory "/D"):

start "Your Title" /D "C:\Program Files (x86)\GameSave Manager" /MAX "Maximized Windows" gs_mngr_3.exe
